# How to interpret MAPE value in simulation model?

Tags: r, statistics

I have calculated mape as follows and I got mape value as 0.9576856.

```
mape <- function(actual,pred){
  mape <- mean(abs((actual - pred)/actual))
  return (mape)
}
d1 <- d1[which(d1$actual_wait_time!=0),]
mape(d1$actual_wait_time ,d1$predicted_wait_time)
```

```
Actual wait time summary:

summary(d1$actual_wait_time)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   25.00   48.00   55.36   77.00  551.00
```

```
Predicted wait time summary:

summary(d1$predicted_wait_time)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    6.00   24.00   31.37   44.00  444.00
```

How to interpret mape value?